# Importing new Animations to a Existing Character from Blender to Unreal Engine

Tags: blender, unreal-engine4

So I'm building a game and I've run into this problem. 
I built a character from scratch in Blender with 5 animations.
I successfully exported the .fbx file and implemented it in Unreal engine.
There are no errors and the game works fine, all 5 animations working.
I now need to add more animations to the character. It's here I'm a bit confused.

I built 5 additional animations in Blender saved the .fbx file but when I try to import it to unreal I get a message saying successful reimport, but the new animations don't show up in the unreal engine file browser.

I am trying to avoid having to rebuild the animation blueprint from scratch. Is there any way I can add animation to unreal and use them with the same character.

I've looked up animation retargeting but is doesn't seem to be working in my case. I have not tried everything but i'm looking for solutions online and keep running into dead ends. Can anyone please help or point me to the correct direction i will be greatful.

The entire project was built in blueprints. There is no Custom C++ Code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, you simply ensure the Root bone in Blender is named something other than "Armature" and export it as .fbx file. Import it in Unreal using your existing Skeletal Mesh.

Answer (score 0):

When you import the animation fbx files there should be a dialog box asking you which skeleton you want to apply the animation to, in most cases this should be enough for targeting the animation to the specified skeleton.  You just want to make sure all of your skeletal meshes are targeting the same skeleton.